# Regex to get paths in rails app

Tags: regex, perl

I am writing a perlscript to glob all the files using the git log from my rails app.
I need help capturing paths from a git stat output.

example :

```
  app/controllers/bottled_lot_controller.rb          |   18 -\
  app/models/kastar.rb          |   18 -\
  app/helpers/bottled_helper.rb          |   18 -\
```

My regexp is not working for the all the lines like these
anyone have a better idea?

```
[a-z]*\/[a-z]*\/[a-z || _ ]*.rb
```

Comment: Your perl code, or it didn't happen..

Comment: I dont need help with the perl script just the regexp to capture the paths into a variable.

Comment: I assume that `.rb` is last thing you want to match, `[a-z]*\/[a-z]*\/[_a-z]*[.]rb`

Comment: You're saying your regexp doesn't match all the 3 lines pasted above?

Comment: @mpapec you're missing an `_`: `[a-z]*\/[a-z]*\/[a-z_]*[.]rb`

Comment: @Matt you're right, it would be better to use `\w` but it seems that lower case is required..

Comment: Would you need to also capture paths like these: `app/bottled_helper.rb`, `bottled_helper.rb `? If so, you may use this regexp: `[a-z]*\/*?[a-z]*?\/?[a-z_]*[.]rb`

Comment: yes I edited my regexp now it works. @Matt can you explain why the || is not valid here? Nicolae Olariu yes I do want to capture like that

Comment: @Stacked-for-life: Everything inside a character class is taken as a literal character except for an initial `^` that negates the class, and a `-` that indicates a range. So `[a-z || _ ]` is the same as `[a-z |_]` which matches a lower-case letter, a space, a pipe, or an underscore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern contains some mistakes, but it could work for you if you used the `/x` modifier so that embedded spaces were insignificant

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  next unless /([a-z]*\/[a-z]*\/[a-z || _ ]*.rb)/x;
  print $1, "\n";
}

__DATA__
  app/controllers/bottled_lot_controller.rb          |   18 -\
  app/models/kastar.rb          |   18 -\
  app/helpers/bottled_helper.rb          |   18 -\
```

**output**

```
app/controllers/bottled_lot_controller.rb
app/models/kastar.rb
app/helpers/bottled_helper.rb
```

The problem is that the character class `[a-z || _ ]` matches a single character that may be a lower case letter, a space, a pipe `|` or an underscore `_`. A repeated character inside a character class has no additional effect, and since there are no pipe characters in your data you simply need to avoid matching space characters, which is the effect that the `/x` modifier has.

The character class you want here is just `[a-z_]`, and as you can change the regex delimiter to avoid having to escape the slash, the complete pattern would look like

```
m{([a-z]+/[a-z]+/[a-z_]+\.rb)}
```

And if you change the `next unless` line in the above program to

```
next unless m{([a-z]+/[a-z]+/[a-z_]+\.rb)};
```

then it continues to work correctly, but this time for the right reasons!

---

**Update**

Since you have indicated that you also want to accept paths that start with zero or more path segments, you should use this pattern instead

```
next unless m{ ( (?: [a-z]+/ )* [a-z_]+\.rb ) }x;
```

Comment: Will it do it for paths like these: `app/bottled_helper.rb`, `bottled_helper.rb`?

Comment: @Stacked-for-life: Your specification is changing rapidly! So your files aren't all Ruby files. Do you want to check the file type at all? Are there ever any upper case letters or digits in the path or the filename?

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu: It will now that the OP has said he's interested in files that look like that and I have added an update!

Answer (score 1):

Input:

```
appTestParent/app/models/bottled_lot_controller.rb      rb rb    |   18 -\
app/controllers/bottled_lot_controller.rb          |   18 -\
app/models/kastar.rb          |   18 -\
app/helpers/bottled_helper.rb          |   18 -\
app/bottled_helper.rb          |   18 -\
bottled_helper.rb          |   18 -\
```

You could try the following regexp: `[a-z_]*?\/*?.*[.]rb` which will give you the following output:

```
appTestParent/app/models/bottled_lot_controller.rb
app/controllers/bottled_lot_controller.rb
app/models/kastar.rb
app/helpers/bottled_helper.rb
app/bottled_helper.rb
bottled_helper.rb
```

Comment: Your regex was right in the first place. Now you are relying on there being no `rb` after the end of the file

Comment: @Borodin I know, but I thought there will be no `rb` after the end of the filename :-). Regexp updated.

Answer (score 1):

Because the data is from a git log, I think we can assume more well formed data then one would find in a general file system search.  Namely, it's probably sufficient to just look for the `.rb` extension as the hard boundary condition.

I'd therefore probably just use the following regex:

```
(?:\w+/)*\w+\.rb
```